# Magento frequent database connection issue

Tags: magento-1.9, database

My Magento website has a separate web server and the database server is different (so basically it's a remote connection). I have a test site as well that has a separate database on same remote database server. Oftentimes I see database disconnection issue in my main Magento store, however my test site works smoothly. What's the issue?

I see Cloudflare error 524 most of the times and when I restart the database server I get "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

After some time, everything starts working fine on it's own. I get any reports in var/Log files.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there are too many open connections between the web and database servers.

These connections (keep-alive PDO) are usually cached in the session data, so you wouldn't notice it for a development site with only minimal activity... but it would greatly affect the total number of customers able to connect at the same time.

Comment: I see. So what's the solution for the issue?.

Comment: The easiest is to just restart the MySQL server. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html.  Or if you have permission, you can use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to view all connections, and `KILL` the process ID's you want to kill.